# Can I add an image to an ASP.NET button?

Tags: asp.net, css, button

I want to add an image, instead of the default button.

I already have a CSS class for the image, will this work?

```
<asp:Button ID="..." CssClass=""/>
```

I am trying it now, and the image is all scrunched up. Maybe it's a CSS issue?

Comment: Yes, you can do this, just be sure to set the width and height of the class in your CSS to prevent the scrunching

Comment: What version of ASP.NET?  This is pertinent info.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Why not use an [ImageButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx) control?

Comment: I'm styling an existing app, it has events tied to it already etc.

Comment: Use an image button with the same name as your button and it will pick up all of the events.

Comment: actually no it won't, += new Eventhandler breaks, have to use ImageClickEventhandler

Comment: I went with the imagebutton, button image looked funny when clicked.

Comment: when i add image button, the url of the image is something like"localhost/Images/...." so it includes local url. What happens when I want to put that project in a server(copying the project from my local to a production server ?) Does the link change properly ?

Comment: @abidinberkay Give the link as "~/images/fwac.gif" or whatever. The "~" means "with the current domain and context". If you aren't using contexts, you could just give a relative link

Answer (score 4):

Although you can "replace" a button with an image using the following CSS...

```
.className {
   background: url(http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png) no-repeat 0 0;
   border: 0;
   height: 61px;
   width: 250px
}
```

...the best thing to do here is use an ImageButton control because it will allow you to use alternate text (for accessibility).

Answer (score 3):

I actually prefer to use the html button form element and make it runat=server. The button element can hold other elements inside it. You can even add formatting inside it with span's or strong's. Here is an example:

```
<button id="BtnSave" runat="server"><img src="Images/save.png" />Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I quite get what the issue is. You can add an image into the ASP button but it depends how its set up as to whether it fits in properly. putting in a background images to asp buttons regularly gives you a dodgy shaped button or a background image with a text overlay because its missing an image tag. such as the image with "SUBMIT QUERY" over the top of it.

As an easy way of doing it I use a "blankspace.gif" file across my website. its a 1x1 pixel blank gif file and I resize it to replace an image on the website.

as I dont use CSS to replace an image I use CSS Sprites to reduce queries. My website was originally 150kb for the homepage and had about 140-150 requests to load the home page. By creating a sprite I killed off the requests compressed the image size to a fraction of the size and it works perfect and any of the areas you need an image file to size it up properly just use the same blankspace.gif image.

```
<asp:ImageButton class="signup" ID="btn_newsletter" ImageUrl="~/xx/xx/blankspace.gif" Width="87px" Height="28px" runat="server" /
```

If you see the above the class loads the background image in the css but this leaves the button with the "submit Query" text over it as it needs an image so replacing it with a preloaded image means you got rid of the request and still have the image in the css.

Done.

Comment: You're using an ImageButton, not a Button.  The question was to see if a standard Button could contain an image.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a Css class of "image" :

```
input.image { 
  background: url(/i/bg.png) no-repeat top left; 
  width: /* img-width */; 
  height: /* img-height */ 
}
```

If you don't know what the image width and height are, you can set this dynamically with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
.my_btn{ 
  font-family:Arial; 
  font-size:10pt; 
  font-weight:normal; 
  height:30px; 
  line-height:30px; 
  width:98px; 
  border:0px;
  background-image:url('../Images/menu_image.png'); 
  cursor:pointer;
}

<asp:Button ID="clickme" runat="server" Text="Click" CssClass="my_btn" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add image to asp.net button. you dont need to use only image button or link button. When displaying button on browser, it is converting to html button as default. So you can use its "Style" properties for adding image. My example is below. I hope it works for you.

```
Style="background-image:url('Image/1.png');"
```

You can change image location with using

```
background-repeat
```

properties. So you can write a button like below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" Style="background-image:url('Image/1.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat"/>
```