# Validate webform onClick event of LinkButton in ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, form-submit, asplinkbutton

In Asp.net I am using [this](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html) JQuery validation plugin.
It works perfect for `<asp:Button>` control. But if I use `<asp:LinkButton>` it does not validate the form and allows it to call code behind method.

Why is this happening? How can I able to validate form `onClick` event of `<asp:LinkButton>`?

EDIT: The problem with `<asp:button>` is we cannot able to add image on it. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510401/can-i-add-an-image-to-an-asp-net-button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to add a click function that returns false if the form is not valid:

```
$("#<%= tb.ClientID %>").click(function() {
       return $('form').valid();
})
```

more : 
[ASP.NET LinkButton / ImageButton and JQuery Validate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649762/asp-net-linkbutton-imagebutton-and-jquery-validate)
Hope this will help !!!

Comment: thanks for reply, but `#('form').valid();` is not working for the Validation plugin.

Comment: `return jQuery('#formID').validationEngine('validate'));` worked for the validation plugin I have been using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnClientClick` in order to call your client method

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick.aspx

Nota : OnClick is for ServerSide, OnClientClick is for Client Side